# How to extract the text and values BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have problem to extract the text and values by using . the web is like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVSA8.png)

I want to get the values for "Capacity d'accueil" and "Salles de bain"
But I do not know how to get the tags, because there is not attributes after div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have tags or any other classifiers you can count on, you're just going to have to know which number element you want and then using something like `find_all` and index into the array.